# Button click function does not find the child component function after using ngif

Tags: html, angular

The button click event used to call the child component function correctly, but it stopped working after using *ngif for "if-else" condition

```
<div class="modal-header border-0" style="display: block;">
  <div>
    <h4 class="modal-title text-primary float-left" id="exampleModalLabel">Scheduling</h4>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModal()"><span
      aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn bg-primary text-white float-right"
    (click)="zoneScheduleComp.saveData()">Save</button>
</div><br>
<!-- <app-zone-scheduling #zoneScheduleComp [m_nZoneNum]=0></app-zone-scheduling> --> <!-- save button correctly called the saveData() function -->
<div *ngIf="zoneComponent.m_nZoneNum===1; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div> <!-- save button can not find the saveData() function -->
<ng-template #thenBlock><app-zone-scheduling #zoneScheduleComp [m_nZoneNum]=1></app-zone-scheduling></ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock><app-zone-scheduling #zoneScheduleComp [m_nZoneNum]=0></app-zone-scheduling></ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngIf` encapsulates all the elements inside the block including the element it's placed on. This means that when the page loads, both those templates will be encapsulated within the `ngIf` and the `button` will hence not have access to the local variables. We can solve this by using `ViewChild` in the component to make sure we get access to the local variables.

```js
@ViewChild('zoneScheduleComp', {static: false}) zoneScheduleComp: ZoneSchedulingComponent; // replace ZoneSchedulingComponent with the name of the app-zone-scheduling component
```

Note the `static: false` is important as setting this parameter to `false` is what ensures that query matches which depend on `ngIf` will be resolved.

Your button should now be able to resolve the `zoneScheduleComp` template reference and `saveData` will be called.

Comment: wow, it works. thanks a lot. I do not quite understand your comment on that line of code. I just copied it to my ZoneSchedulingComponent class, I did not change any names in my HTML and ts file.